# Is the direct use of UDP/TCP sockets becoming a last resort for use in production code?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp, message-queue, messaging

Recently, I created a lightweight wrapper for the C++ boost asio library for some network communication. I used it to prototype some new functionality. We quickly moved over to a system that utilized Kafka to take advantage of an existing microservice framework when more internal funding came our way. No problem, I figured we would move to a different network model later on, and the internals were more important to my job than the network communication.

My question is, with the amount of technologies that abstract away network interfaces, (i.e. Kafka, grpc, ActiveMQ, ZeroMQ, etc.) are the use of base TCP/UDP sockets becoming more of a last resort, where software architects try to find an existing broker/stream processor/network message passing tool to fit their model? Or are there still many new production developments utilizing base level TCP/UDP sockets, not including those who solely write network libraries such as those mentioned above?

Note that I don't work with Kafka, grpc etc. in my line of work, but I have used UDP/TCP sockets extensively in the past. So forgive any misunderstanding of those particular technologies.

Comment: All of the tools you've listed (including JSON-RPC over HTTP) **do** use TCP/UDP sockets. None of them have a goal of abstracting network interfaces; they simply define a layer 7 protocol, which I assume you did too for your own app to function beyond arbitrary byte streams... I don't understand the question.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes they do use them, but they abstract the direct use of the socket away from the user via their API or as you stated the application level, correct? (i.e. you are not calling send, sendto, recv, recvfrom from your code anymore) The question is not whether sockets will go away, its whether software engineers will tend to not use them directly (i.e. establish there own application layer protocol) in favor of trying to use one of the many technologies such as the ones stated above.

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be, should new programmers spend more time learning technologies such as Kafka, instead of learning how to create and use TCP/UDP sockets native to the language?

Comment: That ultimately depends on your goal. Do you actually want to get up and running (as well as have enterprise support in many cases due to SaaS solutions)? Or do you want to micro optimize your network communication layer?